# Is it possible for an iOS app to programmatically know if the device has an active connection to APNS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

iOS devices maintain a TCP connection to APNS Push Servers on port 5223 if notifications are enabled.

Is it possible for my app to know if such a connection is currently active? This is not a question about whether notification settings are enabled, but having been enabled if the device is currently connected to the APNS service.

Although the APNS service is not guaranteed reliable, it is useful in my application to let the user know if they are currently able/unable to receive notifications. The device could be blocked by firewalls, or the connection to APNS may be in the process of being retried etc.

(I know developers can check for this by watching the output of APSD using the PersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig profile, but this is not a end user option)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. The whole point is to get the apps to stop worrying about this. When you register the device for push notifications, either it will pass or fail. You should always handle the failure case on app startup and inform the user in some way.

Comment: Thanks. As I noted, it is easy to handle the permissions and registration success/failure. This is a question about current status after the notifications are enabled, and the push registration has succeeded. Essentially, if the device has an active connection to APNS this very instance.  This is useful for IM or VOIP applications.